# How to solve to compile correctly?

Tags: cmake, ros

Any idea of how I have to modify the CMake file?

```
CMakeFiles/auv_absolute_position.dir/src/auv_absolute_position.cpp.o: nella funzione "compute_auv_positionCallback(boost::shared_ptr<wmcs_lib::USBLPositioning_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)":
auv_absolute_position.cpp:(.text+0x144): riferimento non definito a "ne2ll(Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>)"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
auv/auv_gnc/CMakeFiles/auv_absolute_position.dir/build.make:114: recipe for target '/home/valeria/catkin_ws/devel/lib/auv_gnc/auv_absolute_position' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/valeria/catkin_ws/devel/lib/auv_gnc/auv_absolute_position] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2416: recipe for target 'auv/auv_gnc/CMakeFiles/auv_absolute_position.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [auv/auv_gnc/CMakeFiles/auv_absolute_position.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We cannot suggest solutions for how to modify your CMake file without seeing the file itself! Please add your CMake file to your question post.

Comment: `riferimento non definito a` - what does that mean? Please reset your locale to C or to english before compiling with for example `export LC_ALL=C`. You tagged `ros` - how is this related to the Robot Operating System?